# problem using cv2 to save a video from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, opencv

I use python 3.6 and the latest version of opencv

I have a numpy matrix called `mat`, with shape (158, 27648)
each row of `mat` holdes of the pixel values for a single frame in greyscale.
so to get frame one:

```
frame_one = mat[1,:].reshape(144,192)
```

the size of each frame is (144,192)

and when I use:

```
plt.imshow(frame_one)
```

i get the result I expect to get - a frame from a video

now, I would like to save all of the files into a .avi video. I tried:

```
import cv2
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output6.avi', 1145656920, 15, (144, 192), 0)
for i in range(156):
    frame = mat[i,:].reshape(144,192)
    frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis = 2)
    frame = (np.concatenate([frame, frame, frame], axis = 2) / np.max(frame)) * 255
    #frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    out.write(frame.astype(int))
out.release()
```

and many versions of this code: without the devision by max and 255 multiplication , with only one of them, without the extra dimensions, switching the videoreader height and weight, changing codec to -1.. nothing works. I keep getting an -unreadable by my media player- video.

Comment: Did you try as a debugging step, to include plt.imshow(frame) inside the loop, just to make sure you are collecting right frame?

Comment: `out.write(frame.astype(int))` -- doesn't that raise an assert? At least 4.1 complains about the data type not being an 8 bit integer...

Comment: In the constructor of `VideoWriter`, you set `isColor` to 0, saying it should be a grayscale video. Then you proceed to write 3 channel arrays.

Comment: Finally, you set the VideoWriter to write video with size (width=144, height=192). Then you feed it frames with 144 rows and 192 columns (i.e. width=192, height=144).